# HTTP Post in Swift to PHP gives code=3840

Tags: php, ios, swift

I'm trying to send an app receipt string to my server which in turn queries Apple's verifyReceipt endpoint, however I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

If I hard code the receipt string into my PHP, I receive the correct JSON output as follows:

```
string(2759) "{ "receipt":{"receipt_type":"ProductionSandbox", "adam_id":0, "app_item_id":0, "bundle_id":"com.Test.SQLExplorer", "application_version":"1", "download_id":0, "version_external_identifier":0, "receipt_creation_date":"2020-05-06 15:24:21 Etc/GMT", "receipt_creation_date_ms":"1588778661000", "receipt_creation_date_pst":"2020-05-06 08:24:21 America/Los_Angeles", "request_date":"2020-05-06 15:55:01 Etc/GMT", "request_date_ms":"1588780501918", "request_date_pst":"2020-05-06 08:55:01 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1375340400000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles", "original_application_version":"1.0", "in_app":[ {"quantity":"1", "product_id":"com.Test.SQLExplorer.extrasubject", "transaction_id":"1000000659868895", "original_transaction_id":"1000000659868895", "purchase_date":"2020-05-04 10:55:57 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1588589757000", "purchase_date_pst":"2020-05-04 03:55:57 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2020-05-04 10:55:57 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1588589757000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2020-05-04 03:55:57 America/Los_Angeles", "is_trial_period":"false"}, {"quantity":"1", "product_id":"com.Test.SQLExplorer.IAP2", "transaction_id":"1000000659963594", "original_transaction_id":"1000000659963594", "purchase_date":"2020-05-04 14:27:40 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1588602460000", "purchase_date_pst":"2020-05-04 07:27:40 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2020-05-04 14:27:40 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1588602460000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2020-05-04 07:27:40 America/Los_Angeles", "is_trial_period":"false"}, {"quantity":"1", "product_id":"com.Test.SQLExplorer.IAP3", "transaction_id":"1000000660362367", "original_transaction_id":"1000000660362367", "purchase_date":"2020-05-05 12:55:01 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1588683301000", "purchase_date_pst":"2020-05-05 05:55:01 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2020-05-05 12:55:01 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1588683301000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2020-05-05 05:55:01 America/Los_Angeles", "is_trial_period":"false"}, {"quantity":"1", "product_id":"com.Test.SQLExplorer.IAP1", "transaction_id":"1000000659963406", "original_transaction_id":"1000000659963406", "purchase_date":"2020-05-04 14:26:57 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1588602417000", "purchase_date_pst":"2020-05-04 07:26:57 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2020-05-04 14:26:57 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1588602417000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2020-05-04 07:26:57 America/Los_Angeles", "is_trial_period":"false"}]}, "status":0, "environment":"Sandbox"}"
```

But when I use in the following HTTP POST request it fails with the error, which suggests the problem lies therein. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

#### POST

```
func sendReceipt(receiptString: String) {
        let basePath = "https://www.example.com/validate.php"
        let pathAsURL: URL = URL(string: basePath)!
        let parameterDictionary = ["encodedReceipt" : receiptString]
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: pathAsURL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameterDictionary, options: []) else { return }
        request.httpBody = httpBody

        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print(json)
                }catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            }
        .resume()
    }
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
  
//Read input from POST request
$inputreceipt = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    
//Get receiptstring from json input
$receipt_data = $inputreceipt['encodedReceipt'];
    
//JSON bundle to be sent to app store
$data = json_encode(["receipt-data" => $receipt_data]);
    
//$url = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";    //production
$url = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";  //sandbox

echo post($url,$data);

function post($url, $data, $headerArray = array())
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if (array() === $headerArray)
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,["Content-type:application/json;charset='utf-8'","Accept:application/json"]);

    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: A 3840 error could indicate your JSON is invalid.

Comment: Instead of manually building the json, do: `$data = json_encode(["receipt-data" => $receipt_data]);`. Using `json_encode()` also helps out with escaping characters that might mess up your json (line breaks in values etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of issues which I eventually resolved:

1) In `sendReceipt` method
`let parameterDictionary = ["encodedReceipt" : "\(receiptString)"]` changed to `let parameterDictionary = ["encodedReceipt" : receiptString]`

2) In PHP
`var_dump(post($url,$data));` was adding lots of extra stuff to the returned JSON. Suppressed with `echo post($url,$data);` instead.

Original post updated with correct working code should anyone be interested.